How to add label in default volume indicator in pine-script?
I am using default volume indicator on chart, which changes volume bar color according to previous close price etc.
I would like to add a text(label) inside this volume bar itself, which will show volume[0]/volume[1]   , basically by how many times current volume has grown/shrink since last volume bar.
Also how could I get this reading updated on every single tick?
Please help me, I am new to pine script.
